# React Native Android error trying to nest a view inside a text

Tags: android, reactjs, svg, react-native

I am working on an iphone/android app with react-native that displays weather in a table. In order to create the table, I found this table-layout library for react-native: https://github.com/Gil2015/react-native-table-component and used it in my code. For one of the data rows in my table, I also wanted to display an animated svg file of the weather, so I used this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-image. My code is posted below:

```
tableData = [["Weather" ,this.getIconForWeather(iconsWeather[0]), this.getIconForWeather(iconsWeather[1]), this.getIconForWeather(iconsWeather[2]), this.getIconForWeather(iconsWeather[3]), this.getIconForWeather(iconsWeather[4]), this.getIconForWeather(iconsWeather[5]), this.getIconForWeather(iconsWeather[6]), this.getIconForWeather(iconsWeather[7]), this.getIconForWeather(iconsWeather[8]), this.getIconForWeather(iconsWeather[9])],
            ["Temp", temp[0] + '°', temp[1]+ '°', temp[2]+ '°', temp[3]+ '°', temp[4]+ '°', temp[5]+ '°', temp[6]+ '°', temp[7]+ '°', temp[8]+ '°', temp[9]+ '°'],
            ["Precip" ,precip[0]+'%', precip[1]+'%', precip[2]+'%', precip[3]+'%', precip[4]+'%', precip[5]+'%', precip[6]+'%', precip[7]+'%', precip[8]+'%', precip[9]+'%'],
            ["Humidity" ,humidity[0]+'%', humidity[1]+'%', humidity[2]+'%', humidity[3]+'%', humidity[4]+'%', humidity[5]+'%', humidity[6]+'%', humidity[7]+'%', humidity[8]+'%', humidity[9]+'%'],
          ];

getIconForWeather(iconName) {
return <View style={{height: 40, width: 40, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
              <SVGImage
              style={{ width: 40, height: 40, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
              scrollEnabled = {false}
              source={{uri: icons[iconName]}}
              />
              </View>
}

//this is the part of the code in my return() in render() that displays the table:
<View style={styles.table}>

           {/* Right scrollview wraper */}
           <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
             {/* If parent element is not table element, you should add the type of borderstyle. */}
             <TableWraper borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1,borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.0)',}}>
               <Row data={tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.headText} widthArr={widthArr}/>

               {
                 tableData.map((data, i) => (
                   <Row key={i} data={data} style={[styles.list, i%2 && {backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.0)'}]} widthArr={widthArr} textStyle={styles.listText}/>
                 ))
               }

             </TableWraper>
           </ScrollView>
         </View>
```

The variable `tableData` has all the data that needs to be displayed in the table. The part my question focuses on is `this.getIconForWeather(iconsWeather[#])` and `tableData.map((data, i))`. The function `getIconForWeather(iconName)` returns the code to display an SVG image based on the current weather text (i.e. "rainy", "cloudy", "windy", etc), and the `tableData.map` is responsible for mapping the data onto the table. This code works perfectly on IOS and the table shows animated SVG files, however when I run it on android I get the error:

> "Invariant violation: Nesting of <View> within <Text> is not supported on android."

I have done some testing with the table I am using, and my conclusion is that the table is somehow implementing a `<Text> </Text>` object, and so when I pass `<SVGImage>` into the table data I am getting a nested view error. Is there any way I can bypass this or what are other ways I can display my SVG images on the table in Android?

```
for(let i = 0; i < days; i++){

await weatherBuildGUI.push(
<View key={i} style={styles.weatherDays}>

  <View style={{flex:0.25, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign:'center'}}>{weatherHi[i]}</Text>
  </View>

  <View style={{flex:0.25, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
    <Text style={{textAlign:'center'}}>${weatherLo[i]}</Text>
  </View>

  <View style={{flex:0.25, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
    <Text style={{textAlign:'center', color:clr}}>{weatherDay[i]}</Text>
  </View>

  <View style={{flex:0.25, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
    <Text style={{textAlign:'center', color:clr}}>{weatherIcon[i]}</Text>
  </View>
</View>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The react React Native `<Text>` component only supports nested views on iOS. The `Cell` component in your first [link](https://github.com/Gil2015/react-native-table-component/blob/master/components/cell.js) uses `<Text>` to wrap the data you pass into the table, and since you're passing a `<View>` for your image cell it doesn't work.

I guess you could try to change the `<Cell>` component to support a custom renderer.

Or you could modify the Cell component as follows (line 39):

```
{typeof data === 'object'
  ? <View>{data]</View>}
  : <Text style={[textStyle, styles.text]}>{data}</Text>}
```

Comment: How can I customize a cell component like that? Im new to react native and I would imagine I still need the <Text> </Text> wrap for all my other data like temperature, humidity, etc

Comment: @ghost I've updated the response with a way to do it

Comment: I put that exact code in my cell.js and I get this error: /project/node_modules/react-native-table-component/components/cell.js: Unexpected token, expected } (40:21)
  at cell.js:40:21

Comment: I used this code:       {typeof data === 'object' ? <View>{data}</View> : <Text style={[textStyle, styles.text]}>{data}</Text>} and it worked!!! Does this look right to you, because it comes out laggy on android, but that just might be my simulator. Thanks so much for your help man!

Comment: i am getting a warning tho, do u know how to fix this? it says: "invalid props.style key '0' supplied to view. Bad Object." It also gives me an error saying key '0' is being given to numerous views.

Comment: Any specific place this is happening?

Comment: tableData.map function in the table

Comment: What's does tableData look like? can you console.log it?

Comment: Its actually happening in a different function. I posted the code above in an edit, its all the way on the bottom of the post. Do you know why multiple views are getting the same key? Sometimes i get that warning, but sometimes my app works perfectly, its sort of like a 30% chance of happening, does it have to do with asynchronous stuff? because the code looks good to my eyes.

Comment: Yeah might be an async issue, but shouldn't be react related. Try using `.map()` instead of a for loop and put the awaits inside

Comment: reading this article: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-javascript-map/ it looks like map() lets you read an array but is there away to write/amend the array like I am doing in the for loop?